# Manejar eventos relacionados con la conexión de una USB mediante Java

Tags: java, python

¿Es posible manejar eventos relacionados con el reconocimiento de dispositivos externos en Java o Python? Osea, quiero saber si puedo saber que se conectó una USB al PC mediante Java.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes utilizar la librería [**`usb4java`**](http://usb4java.org/), una implementación del [JSR 80](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=80). Hay varios ejemplos en el libro *Java I/O, 2nd Edition*.<sup>**1**</sup> Uno de ellos es el siguiente: <sup>**2**</sup> <sup>**3**</sup>

```
import javax.usb.*;
import javax.usb.event.*;

public class HotplugListener implements UsbServicesListener {

  public void usbDeviceAttached(UsbServicesEvent event) {
    UsbDevice device = event.getUsbDevice();
    System.out.println(getDeviceInfo(device) + " was added to the bus.");
  }

  public void usbDeviceDetached(UsbServicesEvent event) {
    UsbDevice device = event.getUsbDevice();
    System.out.println(getDeviceInfo(device) + " was removed from the bus.");
  }

  private static String getDeviceInfo(UsbDevice device) {
    try {
      String product = device.getProductString();
      String serial  = device.getSerialNumberString();
      if (product == null) return "Unknown USB device";
      if (serial != null) return product + " " + serial;
      else return product;
    }
    catch (Exception ex) {
    }
    return "Unknown USB device";
  }
}
```

---

*Notas*

1. Harold, Elliotte R. *Java I/O, 2nd Edition* Beijing Sebastopol, CA: O'Reilly, 2006.
2. *Ibid.*, p. 599.
3. [Código](http://www.cafeaulait.org/books/javaio2/ioexamples/23/index.html) también disponible en el [sitio Web](http://www.cafeaulait.org/books/javaio2/) del libro.

Comment: Como se podría agregar a un Frame ? Dado que no veo como colocarlo con un Listener para que cada vez que inserte la USB ejecute determinado código